# Uncrustify ObjC newline after method

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

Is there a way with Uncrustify to add a new line between method declarations and the open brace, similar to `nl_fcall_brace`, but for ObjC methods?

```
- (void)addPendingBuddyRequests:(NSArray *)requests {
}
```

vs.

```
- (void)addPendingBuddyRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{
}
```

Comment: You got to love uncrustify!! Hope there is one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i think you can use the following option for this:

```
# Add or remove newline between function signature and '{'
nl_fdef_brace                            = force   # ignore/add/remove/force
```

Comment: God thanks! I look into this option one hour just now.